# Responsividade para modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tenho uma pagina onde criei uma modal com algumas caixas de texto dentro, nada de muito elaborado. Quando eu mudo a resolução da tela para resoluções muito baixas como 800x600 a minha modal deforma muito, fica muito estreita (eu coloquei ela bem larga) e os itens dentro dela saem de posição também. Como eu posso tratar isso para que ela não deforme tanto assim? Entendo que seja uma questão de resposividade.

configurei a modal em si dessa forma:

```
      #Mod-gravar{ /*botão que chama a modal */
        background-color:#C25C40; 
        border-color:white; 
        position:absolute; 
        left:120px; 
        top:05px; 
        height:40px; 
        border-radius:8px;
        color:white;

    }

    #Mod-gravar:focus{
        background-color:#262626
    }

    #Mod-gravar:hover{
        background-color:#262626
    }


    input[id=cgc]{
    position:absolute;
    width:160px;
    height:auto;
    border:2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin:8px 0;
    outline:none;
    padding:8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition:.3s;
    top: 140px;
    left: 280px;
    }

    input[id=cgc]:focus{
    border-color:#C25C40;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 #C25C40;
    }

    input[id=cliente]{
    position:absolute;
    width:240px;
    height:auto;
    border:2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin:8px 0;
    outline:none;
    padding:8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition:.3s;
    top: 140px;
    left: 30px;
    }

    input[id=cliente]:focus{
    border-color:#C25C40;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 #C25C40;
    }


    input[id=razao]{
    position:absolute;
    width:240px;
    height:auto;
    border:2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin:8px 0;
    outline:none;
    padding:8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition:.3s;
    top: 90px;
    left: 30px;
    }

    input[id=razao]:focus{
    border-color:#C25C40;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 #C25C40;
    }

    button[id=modalcadastrar]{
        width:120px;
        height:auto;
        top:605px;
        right: 140px;
        position:absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;


    }

    button[id=modalfecharcad]{
        width:120px;
        height:auto;
        top:605px;
        position:absolute;

        -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;


    }

    #modaldialog2{
        border:2px solid #C25C40;
        border-radius:8px;
        background-color:#C25C40;
        width:auto;
        min-height:650px;
        margin:auto;
            z-index:110;



    }
```

HTML

```
   <div id="Modal-gravar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="modaldialog2">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#C25C40; color:white;  border-bottom: 0 none; height:45px;">
       <!-- <h5 class="modal-title" style="top:10px;position:absolute;">Criar novo cliente</h5> -->
         <h5 style="top:5px;position:absolute;font: 19px ;"><i class="fas fa-address-card">  Criar novo cliente</i></h5>
    </div>

    <!-- abas -->

    <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#262626;">
    <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event,'aba1')"><i class="far fa-id-badge">  Cadastro Básico</i></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba2')">Indice Fiscal</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba3')">Tabela de Preço</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba4')">Fabricantes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba5')">Fabricantes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba6')">Fabricantes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba7')">Fabricantes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'aba8')">Fabricantes</button>


</div>

<div id="aba1" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Razão" id="razao">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Cliente" id="cliente">
    <input type="text" placeholder="CPF/CNPJ" id="cgc">
</div>

<div id="aba2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 2</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">Conteudo aba 2</p> 
</div>

<div id="aba3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 3</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">preço</p>
</div>

<div id="aba4" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 4</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">teste</p>
</div>

<div id="aba5" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 5</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">teste</p>
</div>  

    <div id="aba6" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 6</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">teste</p>
</div>

        <div id="aba7" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 7</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">teste</p>
</div>

        <div id="aba8" class="tabcontent">
  <h3 style="position: absolute; left:130px;">Aba 8</h3>
  <p style="position: absolute; left:130px; top:50px;">teste</p>
</div>

        </div>



      <div class="modal-footer" style="height:570px; background-color:#262626;border-top: 0 none;">

        <button type="button" name="save" id="modalcadastrar"  class="row btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Criar</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="modalfecharcad" >Voltar</button>

        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript para as abas:

```
function openTab(evt, aba) {

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(aba).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Assim é como eu quero deixa-la, e como ela fica na maioria das resoluções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim é como ela fica em resoluções baixas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é a solução para o seu problema, mas o valor `auto` em `min-width` me parece incorreto, pois se vc deseja uma largura mínima para o elemento, ela não pode ser `auto`. Deveria ser um valor em px, %, 'em' ou 'rem', creio eu.

Comment: Outra coisa é que sem um [mcve] não tem como achar uma resposta pro problema.

Comment: Esse auto no width impediu que a modal mudasse a largura dela sempre que a resolução da tela mudasse, menos para a resolução que eu coloquei.

Comment: Amigo coloque o HTML CSS completo ai, edita a pergunta e inclua o restante do código para a gente poder tentar simular o seu problema... só com esse pedaço de código não da pra te ajudar muito...

Comment: @Sam Perdão se não postei mais coisas para deixar mais facil, o que mais eu devo colocar? O html da modal? O meu problema está especificamente na modal, então creio que em css seja apenas nessa chave mas posso postar o css todo se for necessario.

Comment: Coloquei o html e o css da modal, perdão novamente pelo trabalho kkk

Comment: Ok, mas quais são os itens dentro dela que vc diz estarem saindo da posição? Vc colocou uma modal vazia.

Comment: As caixas de texto (cgc, cliente e razao). Isso acontece quando eu diminuo a resolução da tela, ou dou zoom, pois a modal mesmo não mantem o tamanho.

Comment: Aqui tá normal https://imgur.com/qhjMiMI

Comment: Se o HTML completo da modal não tem como ajudar, pois não se sabe como vc está arrumando os elementos dentro dela.

Comment: Coloquei prints para tentar mostrar melhor.

Comment: @Sam A unica parte que eu não coloquei na html da modal foi a desse menu de abas mas mesmo sem ele eu tenho esse problema. De resto eu coloquei tudo referente a modal.

Comment: Faltou colocar o formulário.

Comment: Vc está usando Bootstrap? Se sim qual Versão?

Comment: Como assim formulario?

Comment: @hugocsl versão 4.1.3

Comment: Não tem um formulário dentro da modal? O código que vc postou não tem nada dentro da modal.

Comment: Com formulario vc quer dizer as caixas de texto que eu coloquei dentro da modal? Ainda sou iniciante, perdão a confusão

Comment: Editei a HTML completa, com as abas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara seu modal não tem o da `div` com classe `modal-body`! Ela é necessária para vc poder colocar o seu conteúdo. Depois disso vc tem que usar o Grid do próprio Bootstrap para controlar o conteúdo que está ali dentro. Isso está descrito na documentação como vc pode ler aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#using-the-grid

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem um exemplo do seu modal sem quebrar o grid de conteúdo.

**OBS:** A forma como vc alinhou os botões com essas classes e propriedades não é o ideal, o BS tem classes próprias para isso, por tanto é possível que vc tb tenha problemas com eles, o indicado é que remova esse CSS e use o grid padrão com as classes nativas do BS. ***Tire um tempo para Ler a documentação e aprender a tabalhar corretamento com o BS***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />

 <style>

  #Mod-gravar{ /*botão que chama a modal */
    background-color:#C25C40; 
    border-color:white; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:120px; 
    top:05px; 
    height:40px; 
    border-radius:8px;
    color:white;
  
   }
  
   #Mod-gravar:focus{
    background-color:#262626
   }
  
   #Mod-gravar:hover{
    background-color:#262626
   }
  
  
   input[id=cgc]{
   position:absolute;
   width:160px;
   height:auto;
   border:2px solid #aaa;
   border-radius:8px;
   margin:8px 0;
   outline:none;
   padding:8px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   transition:.3s;
   top: 140px;
   left: 280px;
   }
  
   input[id=cgc]:focus{
   border-color:#C25C40;
   box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 #C25C40;
   }
  
   input[id=cliente]{
   position:absolute;
   width:240px;
   height:auto;
   border:2px solid #aaa;
   border-radius:8px;
   margin:8px 0;
   outline:none;
   padding:8px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   transition:.3s;
   top: 140px;
   left: 30px;
   }
  
   input[id=cliente]:focus{
   border-color:#C25C40;
   box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 #C25C40;
   }
  
  
   input[id=razao]{
   position:absolute;
   width:240px;
   height:auto;
   border:2px solid #aaa;
   border-radius:8px;
   margin:8px 0;
   outline:none;
   padding:8px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   transition:.3s;
   top: 90px;
   left: 30px;
   }
  
   input[id=razao]:focus{
   border-color:#C25C40;
   box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 #C25C40;
   }
  
   button[id=modalcadastrar]{
    width:120px;
    height:auto;
    top:605px;
    right: 140px;
    position:absolute;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  
  
   }
  
   button[id=modalfecharcad]{
    width:120px;
    height:auto;
    top:605px;
    position:absolute;
  
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  
  
   }
  
   #modaldialog2{
    border:2px solid #C25C40;
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#C25C40;
    width:auto;
    min-height:650px;
    margin:auto;
     z-index:110;
  
  
  
   } 

   [class^="col"] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
   }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   
  
  
  <div id="Modal-gravar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="modaldialog2">
  
   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#C25C40; color:white;  border-bottom: 0 none; height:45px;">
      <!-- <h5 class="modal-title" style="top:10px;position:absolute;">Criar novo cliente</h5> -->
     <h5 style="top:5px;position:absolute;font: 19px ;"><i class="fas fa-address-card">  Criar novo cliente</i></h5>
   </div>
  
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">.col-md-4 .ml-auto</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">.col-md-3 .ml-auto</div>
     <div class="col-md-2 ml-auto">.col-md-2 .ml-auto</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">.col-md-6 .ml-auto</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-9">
       Level 1: .col-sm-9
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-8 .col-sm-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-4 .col-sm-6
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>


  <div class="modal-footer" style="height:570px; background-color:#262626;border-top: 0 none;">
  
    <button type="button" name="save" id="modalcadastrar"  class="row btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Criar</button>
  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="modalfecharcad" >Voltar</button>
  
    </div>
   </div>
  
    </div>
  </div>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
     $('#Modal-gravar').modal('show');
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O div da modal-body eu não tinha colocado na pergunta por erro meu mesmo, editei o html 100% contendo o menu de abas com o conteudo todo. Quanto ao boostrap não tinha me atentado a ele.

Comment: O exemplo que você fez é exatamente o que estou tentando aqui, o conteudo não se desorganizar e sair de dentro da modal quando a resolução for muito baixa (nesse caso é normal da modal estreitar como eu coloquei na print e como aconteceu no seu correto?).

Comment: @GabrielMidão o modal tem uma largura máxima, mas ele eh fluido, assim como o grid dentro dele, por isso vc tem que colocar o conteúdo no grid, pra ele seguir a responsabilidade do modal que esta dentro

Comment: Obrigado Hugo, o problema parece ser essa questão mesmo. Eu não tinha me atentado ao bootstrap.

Comment: @GabrielMidão isso ai jovem! Não deixe de dar uma estudada na documentação, vai te ajudar

Comment: Só para ter certeza, como eu editei o html na pergunta, o modal-body está correto?

Comment: @GabrielMidão cara tá quase, só que seu `form` está totalmente errado, ele não segue nada da documentação ou do Grid. Da uma olhada nesse link, no form que foi montado com as classes do Bootstrap, parta dele como modelo que vai te ajudar. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row